# C get filenames, sizes and permissions using stat

Tags: c, file, subdirectory

I am trying to recursively print all files in directory and its subdirectories with their sizes and permissions. This is the code.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int depth)
{
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *dir_reader;

if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
    return;
if (!(dir_reader = readdir(dir)))
    return;

do {
    char path[1024];
    char absolute_path[1024];
    getcwd(absolute_path, 1024);

    int size;

    if (dir_reader->d_type == DT_DIR) {

        int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, dir_reader->d_name);
        path[len] = 0;
        if (strcmp(dir_reader->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir_reader->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        printf("%*s[%s] %s\n", depth*2, "", dir_reader->d_name,path);
        listdir(path, depth + 1);
    }
    else{
        struct stat st;
        char* tmp_path = path + 1;
        strcat(absolute_path,tmp_path);

        if (stat(dir_reader->d_name, &st) == 0){
            size = st.st_size;
        }

        printf("%*s- %s  %s  %d  ", depth*2, "", dir_reader->d_name, absolute_path, size);
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
        printf( (st.st_mode & S_IXOTH) ? "x" : "-");
        printf("\n");
    }
} while (dir_reader = readdir(dir));
closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately output produces size and permissions only for files that are in the main directory, for the files in subdirectories it is printed only 0 as size and --------- as permissions. I do not see the reason why it happens, IMO recursion should work here and print for files in subdirectories not only names, but also the rest of information (especially that the correct absolute path is being printed every time).

Comment: Note: No need for -1 in `snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1...`  nor `path[len] = 0;`.  checking `len` against negative value or `len >= sizeof(path)` would be good though

Comment: Missing `'/'` in `strcat(absolute_path,tmp_path);`?  Code should not use `st`  if `stat()` fails.

Comment: You manage absolute_path in the wrong way; at every deepness of recursion, you use getcwd(), which is always the same because you don't change "current directory". It would be probably better to use the same method used in the first part of the routine - always work with parameters received, snprintf() them and construct incrementally the new (relative) path.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting a size of 0 is because you're not looking at the right file. In the subdirectories you're passing "myfile.txt" to `stat` not "mysubdir/myfile.txt" so unless there happens to be another "myfile.txt" in the current directory, it won't work.

The solution is simple. You need to have a new string that concatenates the full path and the filename together and pass that to `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the `else` part of the file check:

```
    char* tmp_path = path + 1;
    strcat(absolute_path,tmp_path);
```

The `path` variable has not been set.  Therefore, you're reading uninitialized data, invoking undefined behavior.  You're also not checking for an error when you call `stat`, so you don't know that it's failing.

You need to move the setting of `path` outside of the `if` block so that it occurs for both cases.  You also need to pass `absolute_path` to `stat` instead of `dir_reader->d_name` which is just the filename.

```
// do this outsize of the if
int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", name, dir_reader->d_name);
path[len] = 0;

if (dir_reader->d_type == DT_DIR) {

    if (strcmp(dir_reader->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dir_reader->d_name, "..") == 0)
        continue;
    printf("%*s[%s] %s\n", depth*2, "", dir_reader->d_name,path);
    listdir(path, depth + 1);
}
else{
    struct stat st;
    char* tmp_path = path + 1;
    strcat(absolute_path,tmp_path);

    // use absolute_path to get the file status
    if (stat(absolute_path, &st) == 0){
        size = st.st_size;
    } else {     
        // error, print message
        perror("stat failed");
        continue;
    }
```